# way to "run" a string in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Julia, if we have a string set to a variable :

```
a = "hi"
```

and a function that has the same name as the value of the variable :

```
function hi()
    return "hello"
end
```

can we like parse the variable and then run, or evaluate, the value in the string? If so , how could it be done using these example variable and function?

Comment: The title is broader than the question. Do you just mean "run a function, given a string containing the exact name of that function and no other content" (the explicitly-shown case), or are there other unstated expectations (like compound expressions, or being able to pass arguments, etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in at least two ways:

```
julia> eval(Symbol(a))()
"hello"
```

or

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse(a*"()"))
"hello"
```

In the first way we create a `Symbol` representing the function and a Julia `Symbol` can be evaluated immediately. Once the symbol is parsed to a Julia object we call immediately the function (that is why there is a trailing `()`).

In the second example we parse the Julia code as a `String` and then evaluate it.

A must-read is the meta-programming manual that can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/